# HyperLink in pdf file, opened by UIWebView crashes app on Open option

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios6, uiwebview, uiwebviewdelegate

I open a PDF file in `UIWebView`. The PDF has links, and when I long press the link, an `actionSheet` appears. When tapping on "Open" button, the app crashes for no reasons. This happens on `iOS 6` and not on `iOS 7`.

Comment: Have you tried with actual device?

Comment: Of course. And did also zombies on simulator.

Comment: Nothing? I don't understand why this is happening

Comment: So post the PDF and a demo project that demonstrates this crash on some public site. Without the PDF no one can possibly help you. Also if it works on 7 then it's a moot issue - apple won't fix it in an old release. Disable the ability to open links in 6.

Comment: how can I disable long press on link in webView?